# Pcsx2 unable to play with controller

Tags: controllers, pcsx2

I want to play Gears of War 2 with an Xbox 360 controller in pcsx2. I am running Windows 10 with no problems with FPS or anything except the controller. Even after enabling lilypad and configuring it I'm unable to use it.

What could cause this? How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you installed the Xbox 360 controller driver?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf, should you need to? Its always been pre-installed on windows 10 PCs I use

Comment: @Timelord64 I'm not fully sure about Windows 10, but at least for 7 I had to install drivers for it. I don't have a Win10 machine to test it on, but I can try things out when i get back to my gaming rig.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf as opposed to 7, Windows 10 came with built in Xbox support. Makes me wonder why asker wants to use a secondary program.. it should just automatically connect

Comment: @Timelord64 Lilypad is pcsx2's internal plugin for controller mapping, if that helps. It's needed to map whatever controller you use to the dualshock 2 layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the XPad plugin instead of LilyPad if you're using an X360 Controller.